# Why am I receiving an empty array as a response in my GET route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, crud

I am trying to GET an event by its id but for some reason I am getting an empty array as result in postman.

This is my route:

```
import { events } from '../../../db.json';

const handler = async (req , res) => {
    const evt = events.filter( (ev) => ev.id === req.query.id );
    if(req.method === 'GET'){
        return res.status(201).json(evt);
    }
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Event not found' });
}


export default handler;
```

This is my db.json:

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Recital coldplay",
      "description": "Recital de coldplay en River"
    },
    {
      "title": "Recital metalica",
      "description": "Recital de metalica en velez",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "title": "asdasd",
      "description": "asdasdsa",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "title": "Dave Chappel Standup",
      "description": "Dave Chappel standup comedy",
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "title": "test",
      "description": "teeesest",
      "id": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

the route is `api/events/[id]`

Any reason why if in postman i enter a GET route with the following `api/events/1` instead of showing the first event data I get `[]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `req.params.id` if your route looks like `api/events/:id`

If you want to use `req.query` you can add query parameters like this:

```
api/events?id=1
```

```
// with req.param (api/events/1)
app.get("/api/events/:id", (req, res) => {
  const evt = events.filter((ev) => ev.id === req.params.id);
  res.json(evt);
});

// with req.query (api/events?id=1)
app.get("/api/events", (req, res) => {
  const evt = events.filter((ev) => ev.id === req.query.id);
  res.json(evt);
});
```

Comment: i tried using `req.param.id` but i get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` 
And if use `req.query.id` and go to `localhost:3000/api/events?1` i get all my events instead of the one with the id == 1

Comment: @tukitooo1998 I actually meant `req.params.id`, I updated the answer

Comment: same result with params

Comment: @tukitooo1998 are you using express, could you share more code?

Answer (score 0):

> Your problem lies in comparing string and number type.

Before comparing `req.query.id` turn it to Number type or use instead of number type id string.

```
import { events } from '../../../db.json';

const handler = async (req , res) => {
    const evt = events.filter( (ev) => ev.id === Number(req.query.id) );
    if(req.method === 'GET'){
        return res.status(201).json(evt);
    }
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Event not found' });
}


export default handler;

{
  "events": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Recital coldplay",
      "description": "Recital de coldplay en River"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
app.get("/api/events", (req, res) => {
  const evt = events.filter((ev) => ev.id === parseInt(req.query.id));
  res.json(evt);
});
```

request on postman should be something like this:

```
GET: http://localhost:{PORT}/api/events?id=1
```